# Ubuntu only shows music files on Andrioid Device

Tags: 12.04, android, mtp

I am having trouble browsing my documents on my Android device through my Ubuntu 12.04 
Laptop. It's a Samsung Galaxy Mega and my laptop is a Lenovo Z580. I am able to connect
 and browse my phone but it only shows music or video files. However on Windows they show 
up and I'm able to browse and view them. 
And yes it's Android 4.2.2 and uses MTP for transferring files.
Is there any way I can view these files? (I don't want to use FTP if possible)

Cheers,

sid

Answer (score 0):

Install MTP support on Ubuntu:
Open Terminal and execute the command:

> sudo apt-get install mtp-tools mtpfs

After installing reboot your computer.

Then set your phone to use MTP when connected to the PC.

Once connected, you will see the device in your file manager:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

After struggling to transfer photos from my android sero 7 tablet to ubuntu 14.04, I changed my tablet from mtp(media device) to ptp camera by going to tablet settings, then usb connection, then connect as camera (ptp).  After connecting tablet to computer via usb I clicked on the device folder on the left which still showed as audio but I was able to find my photos through the dcim file and copying them to pictures folder in ubuntu. I tried it twice and e-mailed one photo so far it seems to be working.